# MySql Multiple insert with select

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert multiple rows with select, something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Check(
name, price, 
count, order_id) 
SELECT 
p.name, p.price, 
:count, :order 
FROM Product p 
WHERE p.id 
IN(:id1, :id2, :id3)
```

The problem is that every `:id1, :id2, ...` has own `:coun1, :count2, :count3`.

Comment: :id is the product `id`, :count is the 'count' of this product. I want to make a basket. But the data will be too big. So i want to optimize it, and insert in one query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?:

```
INSERT INTO Check(
name, price, 
count, order_id) 
SELECT 
p.name, p.price, 
IF (id = :id1, :count1, IF (id = :id2, :count2, :count3)), :order 
FROM Product p 
WHERE p.id 
IN(:id1, :id2, :id3)
```

Comment: Thank you, but i think it would be too many "if". Presumably about 100 "if"

Comment: @Urmat Well, How about inserting 100 count records into new `CountTbl` and join with `Product`?

Comment: I think this is genius. Insted of hundreds of queries it would be about 3-4 queries.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be .. create a separate table with those variable id and count like

```
create table tab1(id int, count int);

insert into tab1(id,count) values(:id1, :coun1);
```

Then you can try like

```
INSERT INTO `Check`(
name, price, 
count, order_id) 
SELECT 
p.name, p.price, t.id, t.count 
FROM Product p
JOIN tab1 t on p.id = t.id
```